# Symfony 2.3.6. nested form

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

The question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365634/symfony-2-3-6-nested-forms), but there is a huge difference: I do not have a fixed number of elements that I want to add.

Beneath is a preview of the form and how it should look like. I have a form for a **user entity** which includes different **application entities** and each application entity has several number of **user group entities**.

[image: The way my form should look like - nested entities]

**User**

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_applications")
 */
protected $applications;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserGroup", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_groups")
 */
protected $user_groups;
```

**Application**

```
class Application
{
...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="applications")
 */
protected $users;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserGroup", mappedBy="application")
 */
protected $user_groups;
```

**User group**

```
class UserGroup
{
...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application", inversedBy="user_groups")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="application_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $application;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="user_groups")
 */
protected $users;
```

**UserFormType**

```
class UserFormType extends AbstractType
{
    // Array of applications is generated in the Controller and passed over by the constructor
    private $applications;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    ...

    if ($this->applications && count($this->applications) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($this->applications AS $application)
        {
            $builder->add('applications', 'entity', array
            (
                'class' => 'MyBundle:Application',
                'property' => 'title',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($application)
                {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                        ->where('a.id = :id')
                        ->setParameter('id', $application->getId());
                },
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true
            ));

            $builder->add('user_groups', 'entity', array
            (
                'class' => 'MyBundle:UserGroup',
                'property' => 'title',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($application)
                {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('ug')
                        ->where('ug.application = :application')
                        ->setParameter('application', $application);
                },
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true
            ));
        }
    }
...
```

**PROBLEM:** I have already managed to include the **application** and **user group entities**, but since the **application entities** are added to the formbuilder by a loop, entities are overwritten, such that having multiple applications only one application gets rendered.

Comment: we have some sort of simmilar setup for nested forms but we use collections, maybe it can be a solution for your problem! http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: You traying to add the same field on each iteration (name applications). Its not possible. I suggest create special type for this field with entity subtypes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do want collections. Collections allow for an arbitrary number of elements (which meets your requirements). I think the problem is you should have a `UserGroupType` so that collections work the way you want.

Here is more or less a complete example of your form types. Namespaces and other things omitted.

Controller (remember, you are passing in the `User` object to the form, don't do what you were doing with `private $applications`):

```
...
$user = ...;
$form = $this->createForm(new UserFormType(), $user);
```

Changes to UserFormType:

```
class UserFormType extends AbstractType
{
    // Don't have that $applications member here...

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        //...

        // Your user has many UserGroups, so display each one as a UserGroup field (see UserGroupFormType)
        $builder->add('user_groups', 'collection', array(
            'type'   => new UserGroupFormType()  // I would make this type a service (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services)
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Namespace\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    // ... getname, etc.
}
```

**New UserGroupFormType:**

```
class UserGroupFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Each UserGroup has 1 application and multiple users
        // The entity fields allow you to select these

        $builder->add('application', 'entity', array
        (
            'class' => 'MyBundle:Application',
            'property' => 'title',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($application)
            {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                    ->where('a.id = :id')
                    ->setParameter('id', $application->getId());
            },
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false
        ));

        $builder->add('users', 'entity', array
        (
            'class' => 'MyBundle:User',
            'property' => 'title',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($application)
            {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('ug')
                    ->where('ug.application = :application')
                    ->setParameter('application', $application);
            },
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Namespace\Entity\UserGroup'
        ));
    }

    // ... getname, etc.
}
```

See also http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html
That shows you how to handle adding new UserGroups in the form (if you want that functionality).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! The problem in your solution is that I would not get the hierarchical structure I want: 1. application1; 1.1. group1; 1.2. group2; 2. application2 etc. Second thing is that I edit the user entity and I want to select the app/group - in your solution I would edit the usergroup entity. In the mean time I have splittet the entity-assignment to several forms - but I will mark your answer as accepted.